# What cons should I consider if I put index on every UUID column in my database

Tags: mariadb, uuid

I'm creating a system that is not entirely microservices, but it's getting close to microservices and each module has [its own database](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html).

And based on what I have seen in many online services (Azure, AWS, Google Cloud, etc.) I have used `UUID` (or GUID) for my identifications.

This means that in the `Orders` database, I have `CustomerUuid` column. So, if I want to query a customer's orders, I should use `where CustomerUuid = 'uuid_valu'`.

To boost reading performance for all `UUID` I have this plan to put an index on every `UUID` column.

What negative impacts this decision might have? What are the cons for this strategy?

**Update**

Datebase = MariaDB
Version = 10.10.2

Comment: Why a separate index, why not a clustered primary key? And why do you feel you need UUIDs anyway?

Comment: @Charlieface, because for foreign keys we can't have clustered primary keys.

Comment: I have no idea what that means. If the foreign keys are on different columns then what is the UUID for in the first place? Why use them, why not just use whatever primary key you have?

Comment: @Charlieface, what part of it is ambiguous? When you create a foreign key, the referencing column should be of the same type as the referenced column. Or do I know it wrong? And when your primary key column is UUID, then the foreign key column should also be UUID.

Comment: So if the foreign key column in the other table is supposed to be another type why isn't this column also? Why use UUIDs, why not an incremental `IDENTITY` integer? And if you want to use UUIDs then make the foreign key columns in the child also UUID. You seem to indicate that the UUID must be an entirely separate column, why?

Comment: @Charlieface, I don't use integer, because as I specified in the question it seems that for separate databases in a semi-microservice architecture, primary keys are better to be UUID. And My foreign keys are also of type UUID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you create a foreign key, the referencing column should be of the same type as the referenced column

Absolutely.  They should both be `INT` or both be `UUID` strings or otherwise compatible datatypes.

*If* you are having performance problems, then consider these:

- `INT` (or another numeric datatype) is smaller than UUID, hence slightly faster.
- If your dataset size is bigger than RAM, UUIDs tend to be significantly slower than `INTs`.
- `UUIDs` should be used if you want the *client* apps to assign ids without the help of the database.
- UUIDs can be packed into a smaller datatype.  (cf MariaDB's datatype "UUID" and/or [*UUIDs*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid) )

As for indexing...

- A `FOREIGN KEY` creates an `INDEX` if there is not already a suitable index defined.
- An index helps the performance of `SELECTs`, including `JOINs`.
- A `PRIMARY KEY` is an `INDEX`.
- It is slightly wasteful to add indexes to columns if no query (Select/Update/Delete) will ever use that index.  My point here is that it is the *queries* that determine whether an index is desirable.  (Not the schema.)
- `where CustomerUuid = 'uuid_valu'` -- Yes, for performance, that needs `INDEX(CustomerUuid)` or `PRIMARY KEY(CustomerUuid)` or a suitable `FOREIGN KEY`.  Ditto for `SELECT ... FROM table1  JOIN table2  ON table1.CustomerUuid = table2.CustomerUuid`.

Comment: Thank you for the notes. The point is, we use a JSON file and a database generator to create the database for us. We want to put that logic into the generator. **Add one index to every UUID column**. Otherwise, yes you're right. Each index should be analyzed independently.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati - Does the "generator" use the JSON to design the schema?  Or is the data in JSON?  I hope you are not using a JSON column in a table and trying to index things inside the JSON strings.

Comment: It's using JSON to create the schema. For example: `{ "table": { "name": "Customers", "columns": [] } }`

Comment: What is the name of the "generator" app that converts JSON to "CREATE TABLE ..."?

Comment: It's a home-made utility. It's not a public app.

Comment: I predict the app will become more complex than simply learning to write `CREATE TABLE`.